# Python White Space Diamond

Tags: python-2.7, for-loop, whitespace

I have been stuck on this question for a couple of days. The whole lab question can be found [here.](http://programarcadegames.com/index.php?chapter=lab_loopy_lab)

## Lab 6: Loopy Lab Part 3

Print the following for any positive integer n. Use an input statement to allow the user to enter the value for n and then print the properly sized box.

```
E.g. n = 3

 1 3 5 5 3 1
 3 5     5 3
 5         5
 5         5
 3 5     5 3
 1 3 5 5 3 1

E.g. n = 5

1 3 5 7 9 9 7 5 3 1
3 5 7 9     9 7 5 3
5 7 9         9 7 5
7 9             9 7
9                 9
9                 9
7 9             9 7
5 7 9         9 7 5
3 5 7 9     9 7 5 3
1 3 5 7 9 9 7 5 3 1
```

Don't worry about handling the spacing for multi-digit numbers.

#### This is what I have so far:

```
from __future__ import print_function

for i in range(5):
    for j in range(5-i):
        print (j, end=" ")

    for k in range(i):
        print (" "*(2**2-1), end=" ")

    for l in range(5-i):
        print (l, end=" ")

    print()

for i in range(5):
    for j in range(i+1):
        print (j, end=" ")

    print()
```

I used the import from future function because I am using Python 2.7.3.1. Also, I'm sorry if this seems to be a "noob" question, but I am a beginner and need help. Thank you for all your help! It is appreciated.

Comment: You haven't asked a question.

Comment: @AndrewMedico I clearly asked: "Print the following for any positive integer n." I also attached a link to the entire lab.

Comment: No, you didn't *ask a question*. You pasted your homework assignment and some code. We're not a homework service. Does your code not work? If not, what is it not doing that you expect it to do?

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of an interesting question. Here is my solution, not quite optimized but should be straightforward to understand:

```
n = 5
import string 
numberList = string.letters
# uncomment if you want numbers, i prefer letters
#numberList = [i*2-1 for i in range(1, n+1)]

#              upper             lower
#                V                 V
for n_row in range(0, n) + list(reversed(range(0, n))):    
    # left number
    for number in numberList[:(n-n_row)]:
        print number,
    # space
    for number in range(n_row):
        print ' ', ' ',
    # right number
    for number in reversed(numberList[:(n-n_row)]):
        print number,
    print
```

The double digits really screw up the format so i used letters instead.

```
a b c d e e d c b a
a b c d     d c b a
a b c         c b a
a b             b a
a                 a
a                 a
a b             b a
a b c         c b a
a b c d     d c b a
a b c d e e d c b a
```

Comment: this is not correct, 'a' shouldn't appear on the edge on all lines.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
inputValue = int(input('input interger:'))

base = ' '
for i in range(inputValue):
    base = ' '+str(2*(inputValue-1-i)+1)+base+str(2*(inputValue-1-i)+1)+' '

length = len(base.strip())
graph = []
for j in range(inputValue):
    line = ' '
    for k in range(j):
        line = '  '+line+'  '
    for i in range(inputValue-j):
        line = ' '+str(2*(inputValue-1-i)+1)+line+str(2*(inputValue-1-i)+1)+' '
    line = line.strip()
    length_temp = int((length-len(line))/2)
    for m in range(length_temp):
        line = ' '+line+' '
    graph.append(line)
for j in range(inputValue):
    graph.append(graph[inputValue-1-j])
for line in graph:
    print(line)
```

Or this code, depending on what your desired output is:

```
inputValue = int(input('input interger:'))

base = ' '
for i in range(inputValue):
    base = ' '+str(2*(inputValue-1-i)+1)+base+str(2*(inputValue-1-i)+1)+' '

length = len(base.strip())
graph = []
for j in range(inputValue):
    line = ' '
    for k in range(j):
        line = '  '+line+'  '
    for i in range(inputValue-j):
        line = ' '+str(2*(inputValue-1-i)+1)+line+str(2*(inputValue-1-i)+1)+' '
    line = line.strip()
    length_temp = int((length-len(line)))
    for m in range(length_temp):
        line = line[:int(len(line)/2)]+'  '+line[int(len(line)/2)+1:]
    graph.append(line)
for j in range(inputValue):
    graph.append(graph[inputValue-1-j])
for line in graph:
    print(line)
```